# Pesquisar e Listar através do Json_decode

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao fazer a pesquisa da marca através do input post, preciso listar todos os produtos que contém o id da marca selecionada.
Em baixo esta o meu trecho.

```
$marca = $this->input->post('marca');
$marca  = explode(',', $marca);

if (count($marca) > 0) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($marca as $row) {
                $i++;


    if ($row !== "") {
             if ($row !== "0") {
              $query[] = $row;
              $this->db->where_in(' marca_id ', $query);

                    } 
            }
}       
 }
```

Com esse trecho só lista se no campo `marca_id` tiver um número inteiro, sei que tenho que usar a função `json_decode`, mas não consigo ter o resultado esperado.

Comment: `$marca` tem o json? qual é a estrutura dele?

Comment: Nesse caso a $marca ainda não tem o json

Comment: Não, preciso de percorrer os campos de marca_id e verificar se existe o id da marca seleccionada. se existir deve mostrar o produto

Comment: Então o json eo `$i` não nada relacionado com a pergunta? é só fazer a consulta direto no banco então

Comment: exacto, mas como verificar os ids da marca, dentro do campo marca_id?

Comment: Você conseguiria alterar essa estrutura de banco? Acredito que seria "mas adequado" trabalhar com um único valor no campo marca_id, ou seja, evitar colunas "multivalorada". Do contrário, você terá que retornar todos os registros da coluna, passar por um laço e buscar o ID, isso pode custar mais em termos computacionais. Outra forma, uma "gambi" seria você dá um like por = "%'id'%"

Comment: de facto, ja tinha feito usando duas tabelas onde faço o relacionamento por IDs, mas pensei que usar só uma tabela seria mais fácil...